# How do I set the size of the axes patch so that the plot labels aren't clipped (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a graph in which I've set the axis labels to scientific notation using

`formatter = mpl.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%4.2e')
 axis2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`

However, the axes.patch (or whatever is the right way to express the 'canvas' extent of the plot) doesn't adjust so the tick labels and axis label are clipped:

[image]

How do I adjust the extent of the axes portion of the plot. Changing the page size (figsize = ...) doesn't do it, since that just scales the overall plot area, resulting in the same clipping problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `tight_layout`, which will accommodate the plot in the figure available space.

Example

```
from pylab import *
f = figure()
f.add_subplot(111)
f.tight_layout()
show()
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Just for clarity, I'll add here that if your plot uses other commands, like set_ylabel, tight_layout should be called after all elements of the plot have been added. Basically, it should be the last call before show() or savefig. There is something incompatible with tight_figure and the pdf backend. Calling tight_figure causes a warning "Falling back to Agg renderer". You still get your pdf output, however.

Comment: Using savefig('filename', bbox_inches = 'tight') eliminates the warning, but it also overrides any figsize value set earlier in the code.

Comment: This answer address the question as posed, but there are other reasons one might want to set the plot size without changing the paper size (or the screen area), perhaps to leave larger margins. The savefig keyword arg pad_inches will pad the margins. It's a unary arg - you have to pad all margins the same all around. Also, this padding is applied after the figsize is set, so if you want padding and a specific figsize, substract the padding from the desired size when passing the figsize keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `fig.tight_layout()` (assuming you have a Figure object defined).